# Checking previous input in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering how to check user input that was previously stored in an arraylist.

For example, I am asking a user to enter in letters for which i store into an arraylist. I need to make sure they don't guess the same letter again but I am not sure how. Any tips are appreciated.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String>guesses=new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter a letter");
    String userInput = scan.next();
    guesses.add(userInput);
```

Comment: Iterate over the list and look if the value is already in the list.

Comment: @Jens yeah i tried but I'm not sure how to avoid checking the current input. Like say i am currently at index 3 but i want to check 1 and 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That functionality would work better with a HashSet, since searching for an existing value in a HashSet is faster than in an ArrayList.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<String> guesses=new HashSet<String>();

System.out.println("Enter a letter");
String userInput = scan.next();
if (guesses.contains(userInput)) {
    // the user repeated a guess
} else {
    guesses.add(userInput);
}
```

Of course, if you only accept one character at a time, you can use a simple array to find if a guess is repeated :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean[] guesses=new boolean[26];

System.out.println("Enter a letter");
String userInput = scan.next();
char c = userInput.charAt(0);
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && !guesses[c-'a']) {
    guesses[c-'a']=true;
    // this is a valid guess
} else {
    // this is an invalid guess
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I haven't learned HashSet in class so I couldn't have used it  but the second method works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any duplicates then I would suggest that you use a `HashSet`. To see if the guess was previously done, just call the contains() method.

```
if (!guesses.contains(userInput)) {
    guesses.add(userInput);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Another good thing about `Set` is that it tells you if it could add the item to the set or not, so you can use `if (!guesses.add(userInput)) { /* already in the set */ }` instead. But your answer is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as a good practice you should always code to an interface thus:

```
ArrayList<String>guesses=new ArrayList<String>();
```

should be changed to:

```
List<String>guesses=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now coming back to your question, there are two options:

1. instead of `List` use `Set`, as it avoids duplicates, you can be sure to have unique values (recommended)
2. after every input execute

   ```
   if (!guesses.contains(userInput)) 
       guesses.add(userInput);
   else 
       // if you want you can intimate the user of a duplicate value
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm just learning this so it's still all new to me.